# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar valores de distinto tipo en un arreglo?

Tags: c, array

Tengo que almacenar en arreglos estos 3 campos:

- Código
- Nombre
- Precio

Sé que en c un arreglo solo puede tener valores del mismo tipo de dato. Entonces, ¿cómo puedo almacenar un `int`, `char` y un `float` en un arreglo?

Comment: Podrías hacerlo con estructuras, se llama struct en c, te dejo un link por si te sirve: https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Estructuras_y_Uniones

Comment: Pero con arreglos no hay manera de hacerlo?

Comment: si, es un arreglo de estructuras..

Comment: Podrías crear un arreglo para cada campo. 
int Codigo[];
char Nombre[];
float Precio[];

Y relacionarlos entre sí por medio del índice. Es decir en el espacio de memoria 1 tendrás todo lo relacionado con ese producto. Ejemplo: Codigo[1]:52 | Nombre[1]: Pan | Precio[1]: 10.50.
Igualmente la mejor manera de realizar este tipo de ejercicios es con un arreglo de estructuras, utilizando el link que te dejo a disposición Mario. Un saludo!

Comment: Puedes crear un arreglo para que sea de solo string, luego al leer cada posición del arreglo vas convirtiendo cada valor según al tipo de dato que necesites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
struct articulo
{    
     int codigo;
     char nombre[30];
     float precio;
}
//Creas nuevos articulos así
struct articulo art1;
    /* la forma de insertar valores a un 
     * tipo char en una estructura es usando strcpy
     * de la libreria string.h 
     */
    strcpy(art1.nombre, "Nombre articulo");
    art1.precio = 15.00;
    art1.codigo= 0;

//n numero de articulos.
struct articulo articulos[n]; //Aquí esta el arreglo con los campos.
```

Así puedes acceder a los campos:

> articulo[indice].campo

Ejemplo:

```
printf("\n Nombre: %s ", art1.nombre);
printf("\n Precio: %.2f ", art1.precio);    
printf("\n Codigo: %d ", art1.codigo);
```

Juega con los ciclos y estos metodos y asi puedes requerir la información para todos los campos. Así, por ejemplo:

O como dicen los otros, también puedes crear un arreglo para cada tipo.

```
char nombre[n]; //Esto no sirve para guardar palabras enteras (cadenas de caracteres) solo caracteres individuales.
float precio[n];
int codigo[n];
```

Si guardas la información requerida en el mismo índice para un mismo producto tendrás toda la información del producto con ese índice.

Comment: Yo no recomendaría crear un arreglo para cada dato porque obligaría a tener todos los arreglos sincronizados y eso puede ser complicado... además de tener que pasar varios arreglos a las funciones y pasar a gestionar muchas más variables de gratis

Comment: @Schopenhauer por favor, añade en tu solucion que para acceder a cada campo de un elemento de una matriz de struts es algo como articulos[0].campo. Para completar tu solucion solamente.

Comment: @eferion, tienes razón, yo no lo hubiera hecho de ninguna manera así. Pero si es un trabao de la academia y estan cursos inferiores, y les exigen hacer tal cosa, entonces me parece plausible que se haga de esa manera.

Comment: @Jakala, pensé que era evidente pero lo haré para evitar confusiones y mas problemas a los que menos conocen. Gracias por la sugerencia.